# How to get display:table-cell support in IE? any pure javascript or jQuery workaround?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

How to get `display:table-cell` support in IE? I need lightest solution.

Comment: How about approaching this another way: what features of `display: table-cell` do you need? It might be possible to emulate the required features using a styled `div`, or `span`, for example.

Answer (score 7):

the fastest (but not clean) solution is to wrap your container by a table inside a conditional comment like so

```
<!--[if lte IE 7 ]><table><td><![endif]-->
<div>                   
 <!-- your markup here -->
</div>
<!--[if lte IE 7 ]></td></table><![endif]-->
```

Could be acceptable for a single page, but definitely to avoid in a large scale

otherwise you could specify in detail why are you trying to define a display: table-cell. if this is somewhat related to obtain a vertical alignment of text you could take a look to this snippet of code

http://jsfiddle.net/fcalderan/985e4/

--
edit (after comment)

If you wish to obtain a bottom alignment you could also set `position : relative` to the image container and then `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` to the image

--
edit 2 (after comment)

We are still waiting your code. Anyway the resulting css will be

```
#imagecontainer {   /* or whatever image container you have */
  position: relative;
}

#imagecontainer img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom : 0;
  left: 50%; 
  margin-left:-n/2px; /* where 'n' is width of your image */
}
```

Comment: I need vertically bottom alignment of <img> always.

Comment: please edit your question and provide a snippet of your markup :) my first suggestion is still valid but maybe we can avoid that trick

Comment: I need bottom align and horizontally centered

Answer (score 1):

Probably if you look at the [test site](http://www.brunildo.org/test/disptable.html), which use `display: table-cell` in different combinations, you can easier choose the CSS settings which you need?

Answer (score -3):

> No versions of Internet Explorer
>   (including IE8) support the property
>   values "inline-table", "run-in",
>   "table", "table-caption",
>   "table-cell", "table-column",
>   "table-column-group", "table-row", or
>   "table-row-group".

This is the note from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp)

I think you should try another way.

Comment: W3Schools is wrong as usual. IE8 does support these values. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530751%28v=VS.85%29.aspx