# display :table-cell does not work in ie 7?

Tags: html, css

here display-table does not work in ie7. is there any way apply the same style in ie7

Please help me out.

Comment: for what purpose you need it? sure there is other way than table-cell...

Comment: i have to do table format without using table

Comment: you should try google for 5 minutes before you ask here... [same question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170883/how-to-get-displaytable-cell-support-in-ie-any-pure-javascript-or-jquery-workar). Still I dont get why you need that display: table-cell so much.. there are other ways to achieve that effect.

Comment: if i try other way(like float:left) i can't get increase the border of the cell when content increase. so that i have to use display:table-cell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you desperately need functionality that can only be provided by `display: table-cell` in IE7, you have two choices:

- Use a real `<table>` and suffer unsemantic HTML.
- Use JavaScript for IE7 (and lower) to fix it: http://tanalin.com/en/projects/display-table-htc/