# table-cell in ie6 and 7

Tags: css

I am using a DevExpress ASPxMenu. The html it produces creates a td element between every menu item. I have already asked DevExpress how I can remove this td via a setting or add a class and they say it can't be done (http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q281686.aspx, there is a sample solution attached to that ticket too)

The html/css looks something like (i have added the background:red to highlight the cell):

```
<table class="nav-menu" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="nav-item nav-item-selected">menu 1</td>
        <td id="td0" style="height:1px;width:2px;background:red">
           <div style="height:1px;width:2px;overflow:hidden;"> </div>
        </td>
        <td class="nav-item"> menu 2</td>
        <td id="td1" style="height:1px;width:2px;background:red">
           <div style="height:1px;width:2px;overflow:hidden;"> </div>
        </td>
        <td class="nav-item"> menu 3</td>
        <td id="td2" style="height:1px;width:2px;background:red">
           <div style="height:1px;width:2px;overflow:hidden;"> </div>
        </td>
        <td class="nav-item"> menu 4</td>
        <td id="td3" style="height:1px;width:2px;background:red">
           <div style="height:1px;width:2px;overflow:hidden;"> </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

.nav-menu 
{
    width:400px;
    height:35px;
    background: transparent;
}
.nav-menu td 
{
    display: none;
}
.nav-item
{
    font: 1em/1.167em Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif!important;
    color: #5A81B3;
    padding-left: 4px;  
    display: table-cell!important;
    border: 0px;    
    border-right-color: #DFE9EF;
    border-right-style:Solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;    
 }
 .nav-item-selected,
 .nav-item:hover
 {    
      color: #5A81B3;
      background: url("../images/arrow-nav.gif") no-repeat scroll 8px 100% #DFE9EF; 
  }
```

I have no control over the td with the id (td id="td0") and I don't want it displayed.

The above works great in FF and IE8/9 but not IE6/7. I have tried different displays but they just break FF and IE8/9.

I have looked at [display :table-cell does not work in ie 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956365/display-table-cell-does-not-work-in-ie-7) and [IE7 and the CSS table-cell property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249103/ie7-and-the-css-table-cell-property) but I don't think they help me.

So:

a) how can i get the menu to display similar to table-cell in ie6 or 7

OR

b) how can i get ie6 and 7 to ignore this rule

```
.nav-menu td 
{
    display: none;
}
```

Would prefer to avoid javascript if I can. I also don't want to use the rule below as the id is generated by .net.

```
  #td0 
  {
      display: none;
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hiding the element through `display`, you could hide its visibility. This, however, won't collapse the cell and the space it occupies will still be there. It might (or might not) satisfy your needs:

```
.nav-menu td  {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.nav-menu .nav-item {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

If you really need to get rid of that space, then you can force the cell to occupy zero pixels like this:

```
.nav-menu td  {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0 !important;
}

.nav-menu td div {
    display: none;
}
```

You can view a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/7z7qr/

Comment: I did need to get rid of the space. The 2nd option worked perfectly for me. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is a stylesheet where you can define styles that only certain versions of IE will "see". For example:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

There are [plenty more options](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/). In your IE6/7-specific stylesheet, you can "override" the default styles as desired, but "normal" browsers won't get to see them.

Comment: The problem is that unsetting `display: none` on a table cell seems to be impossible in IE6/7, so a custom stylesheet won't help.

Comment: True for this particular case, but you could work around that using a stylesheet for non-IE (`<!--[if !IE]><!-->`) to add `display: none`... not the most elegant solution though, I'll admit ;-)