# IE7 vertically align middle - not working

Tags: html, css

Please find below the link,

http://jsfiddle.net/anglimass/Y8AvM/

I just wanna my div come's vertically align middle ie7 also.

Can anybody help?

Thanks

---

Sorry guys,

I find out one good solution
Please see below the link,

http://jsfiddle.net/anglimass/ct4tx/

Thanks,

Ref:http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/exactly-center-an-imagediv-horizontally-and-vertically/

Comment: Nanba this is my client requirment.

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble A lot of people. In a a large majority of Corporate environments IE7 is still used. Sometimes even IE6. I know people who are still working on machines running XP. It really isn't that uncommon at all. Businesses don't have the luxury of constantly upgrading to the newest "best" technology.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's not working in IE7 because IE7 [does not support](http://caniuse.com/css-table) `display: table-cell`.

I've even [told you this before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956365/display-table-cell-does-not-work-in-ie-7)

Here's an alternative vertical centering technique that does work in IE7: [How to vertically align an image inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-properly-vertically-align-an-image/7310398#7310398)

Here's the simplest version of the technique from the above answer applied to your code: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Y8AvM/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="inlay">
    <span class="helper"></span><img src="http://goldstudios.net/uploader/uploads/Wildebeest_$1$2ryes3hf$Fl0tEsFaORwBW2seye9qN0.jpg" />
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background: #ddd;
}
.inlay {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.inlay img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.helper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

It works in all modern browsers, and of course, IE7.

Comment: Haha for "I've even told you this before."

Comment: Thanks, it worked for a specific project with an older browser :)

Comment: @CristianB.: I am so sorry that you have to work with IE7 in 2021, that's crazy.