# Centering a div within an absolutely-positioned div

Tags: css

I have two divs, one inside another. The width of the outer div is given in percentage and the inside div is given an `position:absolute`. I want to align the inner div in the center of outer div irrespective of the outer div's width percentage.

It works fine when `position:absolute` is removed from the inner div, but I need that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have the following code:

```
<div class='container' style='width:70%; position:relative'>
   <div style='position:absolute; text-align:center' align='center'>
        //contents
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check out this question, for example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332414/simplest-vertical-alignment-we-can-think-of

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center DIV in DIV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-div-in-div); That question was asked a trillion times out on the web…

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

1. Add `text-align:center` to the `.container` div:

   ```
   .container{
       text-align:center;
   }
   ```
2. If you're trying to center another div or an image etc within `.container` then set those items to have the following `margin:0 auto;`, e.g.

   ```
   .container > div{
       margin: 0 auto;
       /* note that div needs to be a block element and needs a given width */
   }
   ```

That should help with your problem.

Comment: didnt help. I tried doin margin:0 auto too. It also didnt work

Comment: @anaida - can you give us a link to your page or create a jsfiddle using your code?

Comment: Here I want the footer div to align in the center of `75% div`. It works fine when i do `text-align:center` or `margin:0 auto`. But it also needs to be at the bottom of the page. So when I give `position:absolute` to footer div it does not align in the center anymore and shifts towards left. Code Here: http://jsfiddle.net/anaida/C9e6a/1/

Comment: Ah. You never mentioned the position:absolute bit above. It's that which is causing your footer to not center. To get it to align to center give your footer a "left" value of "50%" then give it a negative margin-left of half the width of the footer element.