# css: make text appear vertically centered

Tags: css

I am trying to make some text appear centered in an element, but I can't seem to get it vertically aligned.

I have created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bz8Gn/ The arrow needs to be moved more up.

I have tried `vertical-align:middle` (and top)

```
.cont {
    width:25px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:solid 1px gray;
    height:12px;
    border-radius:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

.arrow {
    font-size:18px;
}

<div class = "cont">
    <span class = "arrow">&#8658</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
.arrow {
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 10px;
}
```

If you want to set the text vertically centered, you have to set the `line-height` in CSS. This only works on this situation.

I tried setting the `line-height` of the arrow to the same as the height of the `.cont` but the result was not... really aligned, so I have to reduce by 2 pixels to make it appear as aligned.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jlratwil/49cjg/

Answer (score 0):

have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/bz8Gn/5/

use position relative to move the object `5px` up

**CODE**

```
.cont {
    width:25px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:solid 1px gray;
    height:12px;
     border-radius:10px;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
}
.arrow {
    font-size:18px;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Your updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bz8Gn/10/)

You can combine `vertical-align` with `line-height`

```
.arrow {
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> the vertical-align property will cause the targeted element to align itself in relation to other inline elements.

*To other inline elements* (except when applied to table cells, where it's applied to the content). Taken from this article (recommended to read): [Understanding CSS’s vertical-align Property](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-vertical-align/).

Now, to solve it. You have different ways to do this:

1. Set the `line-height` of the container box equal to its height:

   ```
   .cont{
       width:25px;
       cursor:pointer;
       border:solid 1px gray;
       height:12px;
       line-height: 12px;
       border-radius:10px;
       text-align:center;
   }

   .arrow{font-size:18px;}
   ```
2. Set the div to `display: table-cell` and give the arrow a `vertical-align: middle`:

   ```
   .cont{
       width:25px;
       cursor:pointer;
       border:solid 1px gray;
       height:12px;
       display: table-cell;
       border-radius:10px;
       text-align:center;
       /* vertical align applied to the contents */ 
       vertical-align: middle;
   }

   .arrow{
       font-size:18px; 
    }
   ```
3. Use absolute positioning or margins to reposition the arrow.

By the way, beware that the second one doesn't work on IE7 and below (see [display :table-cell does not work in ie 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956365/display-table-cell-does-not-work-in-ie-7)).

Answer (score -1):

`vertical-align` only works with block elements. I set the height for you to illustrate how it works.

- Updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bz8Gn/1/