# how to make horizontal elements expand to cover available space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-float, alignment

I'm trying to create a `CSS fluid tab menu`, with a variable number of tabs (similar to what can be seen in Windows, where tabs expand depending on length of contained header, see below).

[image]

Here is an example, I have setup (I need to keep element structure):

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="element">
        <h3>
            <span class="dummy-a">
                <span class="dummy-ui-btn-inner">
                    <span class="dummy-ui-btn-text">very long text is this</span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </h3>
    </div>
     <div class="element">
        <h3>
            <span class="dummy-a">
                <span class="dummy-ui-btn-inner">
                    <span class="dummy-ui-btn-text">Two</span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </h3>
    </div>
     <div class="element">
        <h3>
            <span class="dummy-a">
                <span class="dummy-ui-btn-inner">
                    <span class="dummy-ui-btn-text">Three</span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </h3>
    </div>
     <div class="element">
        <h3>
            <span class="dummy-a">
                <span class="dummy-ui-btn-inner">
                    <span class="dummy-ui-btn-text">Four</span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <h3>
            <span class="dummy-a">
                <span class="dummy-ui-btn-inner">
                    <span class="dummy-ui-btn-text">Five</span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.test { width: 100%; display: table; }
.test .element { border: 1px solid red; float: left; min-width: 19%;  }
.test .element.prelast { border: 1px solid green; }
.test .element.last { float: none !important; overflow: hidden; }
.test .element h3 {  overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; }
```

This will create the following:

[image]

When I shrink the screen, the menu breaks to multiple lines with the last element filling the remaining width:

[image]

My problem is expanding the elements in "the first row" to cover available space once the menu breaks. Simply setting `min-width: 19%` is the problem, but I can't get anything to work.

**Question**:
How would I make the elements in a "row" (it's not really a row, if it breaks into multiple rows) take up all the available space by using CSS only?

**EDIT**:
[Here](http://www.franckreich.de/p/test.html) is a sample page showing what I mean. Shrink the browser window and see how the elements behave. I'm looking for a way to make the first row expand full width AFTER breaking into multiple lines.

**UPDATE**:
I have updated the sample page. See [here](http://www.franckreich.de/p/test.html). I don't have any problems expanding elements while they are all "in one row". The problem starts when the row "breaks" into multiple rows. I would like to know if it's possible to fill the top right gap by making elements expand all across the screen.

Here are two additional screenshots.

[image]

So the gap next to element "Four" needs to be closed

[image]

Now the gap next to element "Three" needs to be closed. You can see it does not work setting something on element "Four", because it will not always be at the top right position. Rather it should be a CSS rule I'm setting on all elements (I guess).

Also, if this can easily be done using Javascript/Jquery, I would also listen for ideas?

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Would you be okay with using some JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I can think of is that since you're already setting your `.test` div to `display: table`, maybe set your `.test .element` to `display: table-cell`.  This will keep them all in the same row and just expand to 100%.  The only thing is that < IE8 doesn't handle `display: table-cell`, but there are solutions around this.  One being [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170883/how-to-get-displaytable-cell-support-in-ie-any-pure-javascript-or-jquery-worka). I'm not sure if this really achieves exactly what you want, but it's a possibility.  I'll keep my subconscious thinking about it though.  Good question!

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/f2CJ6/)

Comment: nope. Already tried that. Setting `display:table-cell` throws off the `.last` element. It's no longer in line with the other elements, plus its width and height are messed up. No idea why though.

Comment: I would have thought that another div inside `.test` set to `display: table-row` should do the trick, if you remove any width declarations on the `table-cell` elements.

Comment: Is that a result of your `float: left` on elements and `float: none` on `.last`?  I'm not getting that effect on the fiddle. (even without a `table-row` div wrapper)

Comment: @Scrimothy: I'm using `float: none` in order to expand the last element to full width once it breaks into a new line.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense (although I wasn't getting that functionality in my fiddle with your unedited code).  But once you define something as a `table-cell` (even if it is actually a `td` element) using `float:left` screws it up.  So if you remove the `float:left` on `.element` and set as `table-cell` they should pop into place.  Again, this doesn't allow for breaking them into multiple rows, but at least you'll stretch out your single row to 100%. A little JS might allow you to add `table-row` elements on the fly, although a little JS would likely allow better solutions than that too.

Answer (score 1):

You may do this with just a `<table>` having width of 100% like;

```
<table class="menu" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>menu1</td>
<td>menu2</td>
<td>menu3</td>
<td>menu4</td>
<td>menu5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and in CSS like;

```
.menu{
    width: 100%;
}
.menu tr td{
    height: 20px;
    background: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu tr td:hover{
    background: white;
}
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/5waXC/)*** is the Live Demo.

Comment: thanks. but it's also not "breakable" into multiple lines, is it? See my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use **Javascript and jQuery** there is a solution.

**[check this Demo](http://jsbin.com/ahomiw/14/edit)**

Personally I don't think this is the best solution but may be it can help you
also this demo is prepared to work for only 2 rows

Comment: thanks for the jsbin. I tried it, but it's not really working. The width is set allright, but I'm looking for a way to expand elements to cover the full screenwidth WHEN the divs break into multiple lines. Covering the screen across a single "line" is no problem. Once it breaks into multiple lines, it gets tricky.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep them in one row and using all the space that they have, no matter how many items you have, using display: table, table-row and table-cell is the actual solution. But you have to use all 3 of them to make it work. So what you need is

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul> <!-- Menus should usually be Lists if it's your choice -->
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and then in css

```
.menu { display: table; width: 100%; }
.menu ul { display: table-row; width: 100%; }
.menu ul li { display: table-cell; }
```

that's all the magic. So your cells always use the full space.

If you want the functionality of multiple lines, you have to use some Javascript to check for your window with and then sperate them in two Lists making it

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Five</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: True - this is possible with Javascript/Jquery, but I had hoped to get by without. Just taking up the available space can be done numerous ways (I'm also doing display:table), but handling "line-breaks"... haven't seen or heard if this is possible with CSS only. Would need something like `max-width: auto-expand`...

Comment: As far as I know using the full space with a flexible line break isn't possible, sorry. You could just make it look like it would use the full space using a background-image that takes the rest of the space but it wouldn't be the same though