# Vertically aligned anchor text

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, vertical-alignment

How can you align the text of an anchor vertically?

I may or may not know the number of lines, so `line-height` trick can't be relied upon.

Hierarchy is as so: `nav ul li a` in 
`<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>`

Hello must be centered but cannot be wrapped.

The a elements have `display: inline-block`

Comment: can you provide some html and css to advise you ? obviously hello will not split on 2 lines :)

Comment: Obviously, Hello is an example. I do not know what might be placed there, which is why I don't really want to rely on `line-height`

Comment: well , you might be right, your plain code shows 'hello' vertical-aligned in its tag displayed as inline, inline-block or even block. Your question is too vague to be properly answered. Can you tell what's wrong with this : http://jsfiddle.net/G4kCz/ ?

Comment: Okay, but now try it with an `a` of a different height to the default - you'll see it's vertically aligned to the top. So really, that jsfiddle only *looks* like it's vertically aligned.

Comment: Agreed that more context is needed for an exact answer, but for a quick test you might try top and bottom padding for vertical centering: http://jsfiddle.net/692gx/1/

Comment: Okay, so how do we make that padding dynamic?

Comment: Have you tried using a `table-cell` display and `vertical-align:middle`? http://jsfiddle.net/G4kCz/3/ 
Probably not the best solution (not my favorite), and it may break the other styles, but it works

Comment: aah, forgot to mention that. `table-cell` isn't supported by IE7, the earliest required target browser.

Comment: just give a proper example of your trouble , with text and the height you need or at least how come there is an height troubling you :) . No clear explanation , no guess (added some tags to your question, keep going with details :) )

Comment: That's inconvenient :) Could you update the problem so it clearly reflects that it needs to work on all browsers including IE7?

Answer (score 0):

Following the solution explained in this thread: [How to get display:table-cell support in IE? any pure javascript or jQuery workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170883/how-to-get-displaytable-cell-support-in-ie-any-pure-javascript-or-jquery-worka)

You can add some additional code to the list, and adjust the height of the block with the height of the td:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td> 
                        <a href="#">Hello</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/G4kCz/4/

Comment: actually, if it is just for vertical-align (middle or else), a simple inline-box added before or after the link will do , even in IE5.5 http://jsfiddle.net/G4kCz/6/ but what does he exactly look for ? a single <a> in a single <li> in a single <ul>  doesn't make much more sence  than a <a> in a single <td> in a single <tr> in a single <table>. **your snippet is missing the <tr> tag** by the way :)

Comment: Actually, your method looks nicer and cleaner than adding a table. I like it. Thanks for pointing about the <tr> (I had purposely left it out because it was that way on the linked solution).